# NHibernate Validator throws System.NotSupportedException after upgrading to 3.1

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

Has anyone encountered this?

After upgrading to NHibernate 3.1, I am receiving the following exception from NHibernate Validator when running NUnit test cases:

> System.NotSupportedException : The invoked member is not supported in
>   a dynamic assembly. at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetManifestResourceStream(String
>   name) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.XmlMappingLoader.AddResource(Assembly
>   assembly, String resource) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.XmlMappingLoader.GetXmlMappingFor(Type type)
>   at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.JITClassMappingFactory.GetExternalDefinitionFor(Type
>   type) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.JITClassMappingFactory.GetClassMapping(Type
>   clazz, ValidatorMode mode) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ClassValidator.InitValidator(Type clazz,
>   IDictionary`2 nestedClassValidators) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ClassValidator..ctor(Type clazz,
>   IConstraintValidatorFactory constraintValidatorFactory, IDictionary`2
>   childClassValidators, IClassValidatorFactory factory) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.StateFullClassValidatorFactory.GetRootValidator(Type
>   type) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine.GetClassValidator(Type
>   entityType) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine.GetElementOrNew(Type
>   entityType) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine.InternalValidate(Object
>   entity, Object[] activeTags) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine.Validate(Object entity,
>   Object[] activeTags) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Event.ValidateEventListener.Validate(Object
>   entity, EntityMode mode) at
>   NHibernate.Validator.Event.ValidatePreUpdateEventListener.OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent
>   event) at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.PreUpdate() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityUpdateAction.cs:
>   line 200 at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityUpdateAction.cs:
>   line 58 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable
>   executable) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line
>   136 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line
>   126 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line
>   170 at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:
>   line 241 at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEventListener.cs:
>   line 19 at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs: line
>   1472 at TestDataAccess.FooTest.TestFoo() in FooTest.cs

As you can see from the stack trace, the error occurs when the session is flushed and NHibernate Validator does its thing.

**Update** I have tried stepping through the NH Validator code and it appears that at some point it is trying to validate the Castle proxy of an entity, rather than the underlying entity itself. This then causes the trouble. No idea what to do about this...

**Update** The problem goes away if I use the LinFu ProxyFactoryFactory, rather than Castle. Unfortunately, LinFu is giving me [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061546/backing-field-for-collection-is-null-when-using-linfu-proxyfactoryfactory-in-nhi) so I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate 3.2 removed the need for external proxy libraries.

They are still supported, but they are not distributed anymore, and the default is to use an internal implementation.

Have you tried upgrading?

---

Update: in order to compile NHibernate Validator for NH 3.2, you need to modify `NHibernateHelper` as follows:

```
public static bool IsProxyFactoryConfigurated()
{
    var f = NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider.ProxyFactoryFactory;
    return f != null;
}
```

For details, read [NHV-116](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHV-116)

Comment: NHibernate Validator is built against 3.1 and has a couple of compilation errors if I try building it against 3.2. Like I said though, the problem goes away if I build against the LinFu proxy provider, and the new NH inbuilt provider is built off LinFu, so I suspect the problem will go away. But the LinFu proxy is giving me other problems, and even tho we don't need the Castle proxy provider it's my understanding that we should still have the choice to use it if we want.

Comment: Well, what are those compilation errors? It can sure be fixed.

Comment: I downloaded NHibernate.Validator and fixed the compilation error, added the change to the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried upgrading to 3.2 then using NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory and received the same exception.